# Cast type to IDisposable - Why?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Saw this. Why the explicit cast to IDisposable? Is this just a shorthand to ensure that IDisposable is called on exiting the using block?

```
using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
  string s = proxy.Stuff()                                    
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This "trick", if you can call it that, is most likely due to `proxy` being of a type that the compiler can't verify really implements `IDisposable`.

The nice thing about the `using` directive, is that if the parameter to it is `null`, then no call to `Dispose` will be done upon exiting the scope of the `using` statement.

So the code you've shown is actually short-hand for:

```
var disposable = proxy as IDisposable;
try
{
    string s = proxy.Stuff();
}
finally
{
    if (disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();
}
```

In other words, it says "if this object implements IDisposable, I need to dispose of it when I'm done with the following piece of code."

Answer (score 4):

This could be required if you are given a `proxy` instance from somewhere and its static type does not implement `IDisposable` but you know that the real type may do and you want to make sure it will be disposed e.g.

```
public class Proxy : ISomeInterface, IDisposable
{
    ...
}

private ISomeInterface Create() { ... }

ISomeInterface proxy = Create();

//won't compile without `as`
using(proxy as IDisposable)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's unnecessary as the `using` statement is explicitly tied to the `IDisposable` interface, [per the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

**edit**: The [C# language spec](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) (sec. 8.13) provides three possible expansions for the `using` statement's syntactic sugar:

> A using statement of the form

```
using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
```

> corresponds to one of three possible expansions. When ResourceType is a non-nullable value type, the expansion is

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

> Otherwise, when ResourceType is a nullable value type or a reference type other than dynamic, the expansion is

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

> Otherwise, when ResourceType is dynamic, the expansion is

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   IDisposable d = (IDisposable)resource;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (d != null) d.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Note that in each one of these expansions the cast is done anyway, so as originally stated, the `as IDisposable` is unnecessary.

Comment: What if "proxy" is an object that the programmer "knows" implements IDisposable, but the compiler can't verify it? Why wouldn't the cast be necessary then?

Comment: Yeah, if there is any reason its to be clear to the reader that `proxy` extends IDisposable

Comment: As long as his proxy is not a WCF proxy, in which case it is not safe to use a using block. But that is another topic.

Comment: Although I love a proper expansion of a using statement, I think that saying the cast is unnecessary is not 100% correct in all scenarios.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: It's not necessary that the programmer knows the object implements `IDisposable`, but rather that it *might* do so, and that in cases where it does it must be disposed.  Note that factories that return things that might require disposal without the return type implementing or inheriting `IDisposable` should be considered an extreme anti-pattern, but if code has to work with such factories, the `using(foo as IDisposable)` is probably the best pattern for doing so.