# Casting to IDisposable before calling Dispose()

Tags: c#, casting, idisposable

What is the reason of casting to **IDisposable** before calling **Dispose()** ?

```
public interface ITransaction : IDisposable
{}
.
.
.

//in some other class:
public void EndTransaction(ITransaction transaction)
{
     if (transaction != null)
     {
          (transaction as IDisposable).Dispose(); 
          // is the following code wrong? transaction.Dispose()

          transaction = null;
     }
}
```

This is one of the concrete implementation of ITransaction:

```
public class NHibernateTransaction : ITransaction
{

     public NHibernateTransaction(NHibernate.ITransaction transaction)
     {
          this.Transaction = transaction;
     }

     protected NHibernate.ITransaction Transaction { get; private set; }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         if ( this.Transaction != null )
         {
             (this.Transaction as IDisposable).Dispose(); // this is NHibernate  ITransaction object
              this.Transaction = null;
         }
      }
```

}

I have seen that code snippet many times in an open source implementation of the repository pattern and I cannot seem to understand the reason behind the cast. Directly calling **transaction.Dispose()** inside the **if clause** should work just fine. Did I miss something?

The original code can be found here:
[NHibernateTransaction.cs](http://code.google.com/p/genericrepository/source/browse/Besnik.GenericRepository.NHibernate/NHibernateUnitOfWork.cs)

Comment: It's just wrong.  Assigning null is wrong too.  It isn't otherwise going to malfunction.  Whomever wrote that doesn't really understand .NET very well.

Comment: This is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695649/cast-type-to-idisposable-why

Comment: @Hans: They are both _unnecessary_. You could call that a wrong style but they're not actually harmful. Agreed on the "doesn't really understand .NET" though.

Comment: @Henk - well, it is harmful to unsuspecting newbie programmers.  Which is wrong-ish.  Kudos to yanong to call it.

Comment: @andrew, the link you've given talks about the 'using' clause. As we know, the 'using' clause casts the object first then check if it is null. If it is null, the Dispose method is not called. The code snippet in question casts the transaction using the 'as' keyword and then immediately calls Dispose. I believe this is a different case.

Comment: @yanong_banikanhon If the code you posted is really what the original code looked like, then Oded is correct in what their INTENT was. It is still not needed though. Maybe someone with knowledge of the changes throughout the years of .NET 1.0 to 4.0 can explain that you used to have to do this.

Comment: @andrew, I've added the link of the original code in my question.

Comment: @HansPassant, @HenkHolterman Suppose you're deriving from a disposable class that didn't make its Dispose method virtual. Your only option is to reimplement IDisposable (and if you're fortunate enough that the base class didn't implement IDisposable as an explicite implementation you could even call `base.Dispose()` in your overwrite.)
Anyone else that is casting to IDisposable before calling Dispose will end up calling your Dispose instead of the base one. So it's not useless and unnecessary and should even be called good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Since `ITransaction` inherits from `IDisposable`, it is possible that the implementer has implemented `IDisposable` as an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), in which case the cast is required in order to access the implemented members.

In such a case, casting ensures that the call will call the `IDisposable.Dispose` method. The cast is done to cover all bases.

If `ITransaction` doesn't inherit from `IDisposable`, but the implementer does, a cast is needed for `Dispose` to be callable. Such a case may fail (throwing an exception) if the implementer does not implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Oded Except that if transaction DOES NOT inherit from IDisposable it will throw a Null exception when .Dispose() is invoked. So it's still wrong. I would question if it was cut-pasted correctly.

Comment: @Andrew, also not entirely correct. The implementing class could implement both `IDisposable` and `ITransaction`, and in that case a cast could succeed.

Comment: @JBSnorro You must of missed when I said when it does not inherit. I did not say when ITransaction does not inherit. When the implementation does not inherit from IDisposable at some point in the chain that code will throw and there is no check.

Comment: Your Edit made it worse: explicit implementation by the class does _not_ play a role here. The parameter is `ITransaction`.

Comment: @Andrew, that's what I'm worried about. If the client developer is not sure about the type of transaction, by doing the cast and then  calling Dispose(), there is a big chance that a null exception will occur. On the other hand, if the client developer is sure that the transaction implements IDisposable, then the cast is pointless.

Comment: @Oded I understand the point you are trying to make now. However, if you take the code I updated my answer with I cannot get it to accidently invoke the other explicitly implemented Dispose()

Answer (score 0):

When calling `Dipose()` on an interface deriving from IDisposable, there is no difference.

There could be a difference when calling `Dispose()` on a class implementing `IDisposable`, because the method `Dispose()` may be implemented explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do this often but I whacked my whole original answer as I understand what Oded is trying to say now. Their intent is to solve this problem:

```
namespace StackOverflow7051864
{
    using System;

    public interface ITransaction : IDisposable {}

    public interface ITryToConfuseDispose
    {
        void Dispose();
    }

    public class Transaction : ITransaction, ITryToConfuseDispose
    {
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Happy");
        }

        void ITryToConfuseDispose.Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Confused");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EndTransaction(new Transaction());
        }

        public static void EndTransaction(ITransaction transaction)
        {
            (transaction as IDisposable).Dispose();

            transaction.Dispose();            
        }
    }
}
```

What does 'transaction.Dispose()' invoke? It invokes `IDisposable.Dispose()`

The problem though, is that since the contract into EndTransaction is ITransaction, it will always invoke the IDisposable version.

Comment: what if `ITransaction` defines its own `Dispose` method?

Comment: @Oded, the ITransaction has no Dispose method of its own. The Dispose() method is implemented in concrete classes (ex. NHibernateTransaction). I will append the relevant code in my original question shortly.

Comment: @Oded That indeed WILL cause problems but I would argue that you still shouldn't be casting to IDisposable to invoke it's Dispose(). The implementor of ITransaction had to use the 'new' keyword on the Dispose() method, meaning they explicitly wanted a different Dispose() to be invoked. I think giving any kind of real world scenario in which this is practical and safe would benefit this question tremendously.