# Using 'as IDisposable' in a using block

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

Edit: My question isn't about a using block and how it works. My question is about the difference in the two ways to do it, shown below.

I'm reading the CQRS Journey Guide, and I don't understand this line of code:

```
using (repo as IDisposable)
```

What does that mean? Why use it as IDisposable? In a typical using block, one doesn't need to use it as IDisposable:

```
using (var repo = this.respositoryFactory()) { // ... }
```

Any idea why the authors wrote it the first way instead of the second way?

This is the method in which that code appears:

```
private Conference.Web.Public.Models.Conference GetConference(string conferenceCode)
{
    var repo = this.repositoryFactory();
    using (repo as IDisposable)
    {
        var conference = repo.Query<Conference>()
            .First(c => c.Code == conferenceCode);
        var conferenceModel =
        new Conference.Web.Public.Models.Conference
        {
            Code = conference.Code,
            Name = conference.Name,
            Description = conference.Description
        };
        return conferenceModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, you cant use any old type in a using block, it has to be a type that is IDisposable.

Comment: How does `as IDisposable` magically allow the instance to be disposed if its class does not implement `IDisposable`? And if it already implements `IDisposable`, why wouldn't that be enough for the `using` statement? I've never seen it require a cast.

Comment: @iamkrillin You don't have to set something 'as IDisposable' in a using block if it's already disposable.

Comment: @BobHorn You are incorrect, sir, the simple act of putting an instance of an object into a using block does not make it disposable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @iamkrillin: True. That's what `: IDisposable` is for. How does `as IDisposable` fix this?

Comment: all the as statement does is a safe cast operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx  I suspect the author done that to make it explicit

Comment: You keep explaining general syntax of the language and somehow expect that to explain why a cast is done here. Why is the cast done?

Comment: well the short answer, the cast is not necessary.

Comment: Good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695649/cast-type-to-idisposable-why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Any idea why the authors wrote it the first way instead of the second way?

This is often due to a misunderstanding of the language feature.  The way you wrote it is the idomatic way to write it in C#:

```
using (var repo = this.respositoryFactory()) 
{
```

The only real advantage to the author's approach would be if `repositoryFactory` could, potentially, return a type which doesn't implement `IDisposable`.  By writing the code via `using (repo as IDisposable)`, the same code could handle non-disposable types.

Most of the time, this isn't an issue.  However, it would be possible that the factory could *optionally* return an `IDisposable` type.  As an example, suppose this method was done within a generic class, and `repositoryFactory` returned an `IRepository<T>`, it would be possible that type may or may not implement `IDiposable`, in which case this approach would handle both cases without imposing an `IDisposable` constraint on the generic type.

Comment: Doesn't that assume that `repositoryFactory` returns a type that implements `IDisposable`? What if it returned object, for example?

Comment: @CodeNaked `repositoryFactory` would have to return an IDisposable or it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @BobHorn - Yes, but if it was a type that may or may not implement `IDisposable`, which may be the case with "factories", then you'd be required to cast it to an `IDisposable`. This doesn't seem to apply to this particular case, but you didn't show the type definition of the `repositoryFactory`.

Comment: @CodeNaked: it throws a compiler error if the return type of the factory does not hold `IDisposable` for certain. It has to return either `IDisposable` or a class/interface that implements it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - That's not true. I could do `using (var m = this.respositoryFactory() as IDisposable)` then `respositoryFactory` can return any object, whether it implements `IDisposable` or not. If it doesn't, then the user is a no-op.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Sorry, you are correct in that it would be a compiler error if you didn't cast. But the point of the cast is to say, if it implements IDisposable, then dispose it as part of the using.

Comment: @CodeNaked: I retract my words, you are correct. It works just fine with the casting. That's a neat trick.

Comment: @CodeNaked: If you say `using m=this.repositoryFactory() as IDisposable`, then if the object returned by `repositoryFactory()` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, `m` will be null.  In the code as originally written, `repo` would hold a reference to the object that doesn't implement `IDisposable` while the using block would perfectly happily guard `null`.

Comment: The issue isn't just with generic types.  It's entirely possible for a factory method whose declared return type does not implement `IDisposable` to create object instances of types which do implement `IDisposable` and which require cleanup.  The non-generic `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is like that.  I would regard such factory methods as an *extreme anti-pattern*, but since such things exist, code which uses them must make do as best it can, and the pattern shown in the original code is probably the best that can be done.

Comment: @CodeNaked: If you declare the variable within the `using` and an object instance doesn't implement `IDisposable`, the fact the variable is null won't only prevent `Dispose` being called on the object (which it should) but *won't allow anything else to be done with the object either*.  Making the declaration separate avoids that problem.

Comment: @supercat Yes, very true - was intended to be an example - will reword to make it more clear that it doesn't require generic types.

Answer (score 3):

Saying `using(X as IDisposable)` instructs the compiler that X identifies a particular *instance* of a type which implements `IDisposable`, then the `using` block should guard that instance, and otherwise it should guard nothing.  Such a usage would be appropriate if the return type of the method `this.repositoryFactory()` did not implement `IDisposable`, but the method would sometimes return instances of types which do implement `IDisposable` and expect it to be called.

Note that any type which will be used as the return type of a factory that may produce `IDisposable` objects needing cleanup should implement `IDisposable`, even if only 99.9% of the objects generated would have `Dispose` methods that do nothing and don't actually have to be called.  The non-generic `IEnumerator` fits that description to a "T", and thus should have implement `IDisposable`, but since it doesn't the best usage pattern is probably:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = myEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
using (enumerator as IDisposable)
{
  ...
}
```

Very similar to what is observed in the code using `repositoryFactory()` above.

Answer (score 0):

if somewhere in the using block the code fails, or reach a point of exception. Its guaranteed that repo is beeing disposed.

Difference between the two lines is that there is no difference. cast to IDisposable is not nessecary, it is purely theorethical. possible differences

- after the using you want to do something with repo.
- cleaner code

Comment: I get that. Wouldn't that be the case for either approach? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: If the return type of `DepositoryFactory` does not implement `IDisposable`, but that method may sometimes generate instances of types which *do* implement `IDisposable` and would thus require cleanup, the `as IDisposable` will be necessary.